# Sumar esquinas de una matriz en Ruby

Tags: ruby, matrices

Tengo una matriz cuadrada. Digamos que la establezco a 3 y pongo como datos 1 a 9, las esquinas serían 1, 3, 7, 9.

Entonces, utilizo este código para encontrarlas y sumarlas:

```
for i in 0..N-1
    for j in 0..N-1
        if(((i==0) || (i==N-1))&&((j==0) || (j==N-1)))
            E[i]=(M[i][j])
            sumaE+=E[i].to_i
        end
    end
end

print("Esquinas:#{E}.\nSuma=#{sumaE}")
```

Funciona porque me da la suma como 20, pero el array me lo da incompleto `["1", nil, "9"].`
Alguien sabe cómo solucionar el `nil`?

(Datos extras: creo que mi ruby es 2.2 )

Comment: En tu código falta la definición de las variables `N`, `E` y `M`

Answer (score 1):

Espero haber comprendido bien lo que quieres. y aunque esta implementación es muy distinta a la que tienes, espero que al menos te sirva de referencia.

Asumiendo que 'matriz cuadrada' signfica:

```
matriz = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
```

Para generar un Array con los extremos de la matriz:

```
extremos = []
extremos << matriz[0][0] # el primero del primer array
extremos << matriz[0][-1] # el último del primer array
extremos << matriz[-1][0] # el primero del último array
extremos << matriz[-1][-1] # el último del último array

extremos # => [1,3,7,9]
```

Para obtener la suma:

```
extremos.inject(:+) # => 20
```

---

> Otra implementación:

```
matriz = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]

extremos = matriz.map{ |a| [a[0], a[-1]] }.minmax.flatten
# => [1, 3, 7, 9]

extremos.inject(:+)
# => 20
```

Comment: +1 Por `minmax`.